# How to make an if function work in a tkinter output box

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, if-statement, tkinter

The premise of my code is to ask for a password and the tkinter gui will return whether it thinks that it is secure or not. However, I cannot seem to get the if function displayed in the output box. Here is the code. (This has been updated to include more code and a further more detailed explanation of my problem.)

```
from tkinter import *

password = Tk()
password.title('Password tester')

label = Label(password, text="Password:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W) 
entry= Entry(width=20, bg='light blue')
entry.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)        #Input box

def click():
  entered_text = entry.get()
  print("click")
  Button(password, text='SUBMIT',width=5, command=click).grid(row=3,column=0, sticky=W)    #Submit button ('Click' is also returned in the shell)

  label = Label(password, text='\n\nPassword strength:')
  label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)

  output = Text(password, width=75, height=6, wrap=WORD, background='light blue')
output.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)    #Output box

if label['text'] =='password':
   output.insert(END, label['text'])#'Cool = output if 'password' entered
   print('Cool')
```

The code now returns 'click,' if 'password' is entered into the'Password:.' box. However, 'click' appears in the shell instead of the GUI, and is supposed to print 'cool' in the 'Password strength:' box, if 'password' is entered.

Comment: Please try to format your code properly because your indentation is a bit incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use an if function. Instead, assign 'password' to a dictionary.

Def click():
Is in the wrong position. Assigning 'password' to a dictionary makes it a lot easier to get an answer in the output. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

def click():
  entered_text = entry.get()
  output.delete(0.0, END)
  strength = pass_Type[entered_text]    #Key press function
  output.insert(END, strength)

Password = Tk()
Password.title('Password tester') 

label = Label(Password, text="Password:")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)    #Entry label

entry = Entry(width=20, bg='light blue')
entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)     #Entry box

Button(Password, text='SUBMIT',width=5, command=click).grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=W)  #Button

label = Label(Password, text='Strength:')
label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)          #Output label

output = Text(Password, width=75, height=6, wrap=WORD, background='light blue')
output.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)                              #Output box 

pass_Type = {
  'password': 'This is a very predicatable password. You should incorporate numbers'
}

password.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
label = Label(password, text='\n\nPassword strength:')
label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)

if label['text'] =='password':
   print("ok")
```

I don't exactly understand your question,

Did you forget using pack() function to display you view ?

Edit :

```
def click():
  entered_text = entry.get()
  print("click")
  # here the code for your check
Button(password, text='SUBMIT',width=5, command=click).grid(row=3,column=0, sticky=W)
```

Comment: is label.textvariable tailored to my code, or used as an example. It comes up with an error if I run it, i get an error. I will edit and explain further

Comment: sorry I made a mistake, it's thank to label['text'] that you can access the text vaue of your label

Comment: Is this an answer? It sounds like you are asking for clarification.

Comment: Yes, I'm waiting for clarification

Comment: The correction you made returns: "'nonetype' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: Oops, I forgot to remove the grid() call, edited, but I don't understand what you really want to do, can you gie us  more explanations ?

Comment: The code now runs fine. However, I wish to display the printed string in the output box I have created.

Comment: Ah, your code returns a boolean, you say print("something") in output wich means None in output, wich is False

Comment: Maybe you should use : 
output.insert(END, label['text'])

Comment: How can I use this to generate a response of 'ok'?

Comment: You should use the text's value in the click function, and remove Button from inside it, the button as no reason for being inside the function

Comment: Could you edit that into your answer? It will be easier for other's to understand

Comment: It now produces a response, but not in the output box provided. It effects the shell instead.